# HP Laptop - Black screen when turned on everything else is working

Tags: laptop-display

I have `HP Pavilion DV4T-2100` model running windows 7. Today when I turn it on I got black screen and it is not showing anything at all. Everything else is working. I can hear fan noise, LEDs lights are blinking and even I can hear window welcome tone when window starts and also as I know my first screen is password screen when that tone is played I type password and press enter and I can hear sound that is played when user login inside system. Only thing that is missing is display as screen is completely black all time. I have done removing battery and pressing power button for 30-60 seconds many times but no success. The screen is remain black all time. Please tell me what is the problem. Is there any defect with hardware or I have to replace anything.

**Edit:**
When connected to external monitor display is showing up but when display is switched to laptop it does not shows up anything it remains black(not completely black but bright black screen). Is there a fault with laptop screen or wire that connects with screen to other part. What is possible fault if it is working with external monitor.

**Edit no. 2:**
Got it checked from a technician and he told me that it is motherboard fault and it needs to be replaced. Is he right about it? Please share your experience if you have replaced same problem.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Anuj

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue when I was working with a client's laptop about a week ago.  The problem was that one of the wires behind the screen was being pinched, hence cutting off the signal.  Worst case scenario, you may have to replace your screen.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Screen is black but its brightness is varying when windows boot up. It is not as black as its look when laptop is off. IS there any problem with graphic card or motherboard.

Comment: @anujprashar Okay, it sounded like the screen was completely black all the time.  In that case, I'm not too sure.  I was just excited to see your question because I would be able to offer a solution.  I hope I was at least somewhat helpful.  Good luck!

Comment: @anujprashar   if you can see glints of information, then it could be a backlight being off or failed. Do the Flashlight trick, or shine some light in there, and see if the LCD pannels are still making a picture, just no backlight.

Comment: Thanks for reply. You are saying that I should shine some light on laptop screen. I done that and nothing is showing up.

Comment: OK.  the blackness varies but no picture. that goes back to what mike was saying, The LCD pannel connection.  By the way good coverage on your question.

Comment: I talked with someone who has same problem and he told me that there was problem with some display ic chip in laptop and he got it replaced and also fan of laptop replaced to get that black screen fault corrected.

Comment: OK got it checked from a technician and he told me that it is motherboard fault and it needs to be replaced.

Comment: @anujprashar That sucks, If the whole motherboard is replaced, isnt that going to cost almost the same as a new computer? And does it prevent that from happening again?  If say he just puts the same thing in that already broke the first time?  Before this happened did the unit get dropped, or overheated?  Myself i usually avoid Major repairs , unless they can show reason that it solutions something. Manufactures send out repair Sheets to the techs.

Comment: @Psycogeek Thanks for replying. The cost of motherboard will be around Rs. 7500 ($150) and it is around 1/5th the price of laptop. I have heard that in US the cost of repair is very high and people usually buy new one instead of repairing the laptop. As I am in India it wont cost as much as in US for repairing a laptop, but it is still a big amount for me . Now I am taking another opinion and I have given my laptop to HP authorized service centre and lets see what is fault according to them. In the days before the problem started, sometimes laptop fan was making noises.

Comment: @anujprasher **I have given my laptop to HP authorized service centre**  Now that is a good idea.  At least a second opinion, and in this situation a better "informed" tech might be better informed about a specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is an IC for display also called "display chip" which gets exhausted.

There are 2 solutions:

1. There is a technique called "reballing" which needs to be done on that chip, basically it's a kind of soldering of the chip.
2. You can change the chip.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, try to replace the inverter. If nothing works after that, then change the cable that connects the motherboad and the display. As a last resort, if nothing else works, change the entire display.